# Unexplainable difference in routes between two resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

In Rails 4, for users as well as organizations I have defined the same routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # Static pages
  root                        'static_pages#home'
  get 'hello'             =>  'static_pages#hello'
  get 'partner'           =>  'static_pages#partner'

  # Messages contact form
  get 'contact'           =>  'messages#new', as: 'contact'
  post 'contact'          =>  'messages#create'

  # Users
  get 'signup'            =>  'users#new'
  resources :users
  get 'admins'            =>  ‘users#index_adm'
  get 'unactivated'       =>  ‘users#index_unactivated'

  # Organizations
  resources :organizations

  # Sessions (for remembering log in log out)
  get    'login'          => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'          => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'         => 'sessions#destroy'

  # Account activation (sends email and uses edit method to change activation status)
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]

  # Password reset
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

end
```

But when I examine through `rake routes`, the paths/routes differ:

```
      signup GET    /signup(.:format)                users#new
       users GET    /users(.:format)                 users#index
             POST   /users(.:format)                 users#create
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)             users#new
  edit_users GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)        users#edit
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)             users#show
             PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)             users#update
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)             users#update
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)             users#destroy

organizations GET   /organizations(.:format)         organizations#index
              POST  /organizations(.:format)         organizations#create
new_organization  GET /organizations/new(.:format)      organizations#new
edit_organization GET /organizations/:id/edit(.:format) organizations#edit
              GET    /organizations/:id(.:format)    organizations#show
              PATCH  /organizations/:id(.:format)    organizations#update
              PUT    /organizations/:id(.:format)    organizations#update
              DELETE /organizations/:id(.:format)    organizations#destroy
```

Notice particularly the last four lines for users and the last four lines for organizations. Here a `users#update PATCH` request relates to 'user path', while the `organizations#update PATCH` request relates to the `edit_organization` path. I would like to have the organization routes the same as for users. Users I've set up following Hartl's railstutorial.org and have added organizations myself. The difference in routes causes problems when trying to update an organization's record.

What have I done differently do that the organizations paths are not similar to that of users?

Comment: could you show us your full routes.rb file?

Comment: So the organization_path seems to not exist, while the user_path does exist.

Comment: Full routes file added to the question.

Comment: What version of rails are you running? I just tried your routes.rb file on 4.2.0 and I'm unable to recreate the problem. Here is my output with those routes: http://pastebin.com/qugUfxCY

Comment: I'm running Rails 4.2.1. Your output is indeed how I would like it to be for me.

Comment: I'm at a loss, tried it on 4.2.1 and got the same (correct) output again unlike you. Do you have anything else that could be influencing rails's behaviour on? Some gems or something in the initialisers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gone. It might have been a problem with the cloud program in which I was working. After restarting my browser suddenly the problem is gone...

Answer (score 0):

The PATCH and PUT operations do not relate to the `edit_organization` or `edit_users` path. When using `resources` rails generates routes for the operations which modify a resource `[PUT, PATCH, DELETE]`  off the singular name of the resource ( `organization_path` ).

I believe you could just be reading the output of `rake routes` wrong - or the output is just faulty. That is unless rails complains that `organization_path` does not exist.

Comment: But then why does it differs between users and organizations, and why in the routes is there no 'organization' in the first "column" while there is 'user'? The problem it is causing: when I submit the edit form for an organization it produces the error: `No route matches [PATCH] "/organization.1"`.

Comment: And when I click to remove a record, it generates the error `No route matches [DELETE] "/organization.10"`.

Comment: Hmm, thats bizarre - you are defining the routes correctly. It might help if you add your form to the question and try running `app.organization_path(id: 1)` from the rails console (`$ rails s`).

Comment: The output should be "/organizations/1"